# PHPStorm/WSL open links in Windows Google Chrome

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, intellij-idea

I have installed the Linux version of PHPStorm in a WSL Ubuntu (Windows 11 host OS).
However, clicking on any HTTP link I get this image and it's unable to open the Chrome Brower in Windows. When in WSL command prompt I type `'/mnt/c/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'` and press enter it opens Chrome. The same thing does not work in PHPStorm.
[image]

Using the same path without `'` I get this error

[image]

I can install Chromium and set it for PHPStorm links, but this is inefficient as I want to use the Windows Version of Chrome for all links.

This apparently is a known bug with WSL
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with WSL and as was suggested in the [linked](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6170) Github bug, restarting WSL helped. The path should be like below without space-escaping or extra quotes.

```
/mnt/c/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first try the problem is probably with the quotes being taken
as part of the file-name.
In the second one, the problem is probably with the blank inside the path.

To solve the problem of the blank, one of the following may work :

- Add an anti-slash before the blank (`\`), or if that fails,
- Use a path-name without blanks, such as by adding inside
  another folder a symbolic link to Chrome, or use a batch file.